parsing/scraping/python/requests/BeautifulSoup4. How to parse this site?
Site: https://www.nieruchomosci-online.pl/szukaj.html?3,mieszkanie,wynajem,,Szczecin:19503
I want to parse all advertisements,except of featured ones.The problem is there are different classes for almost every ad and i cannot gather them to one list. Featured ads can be on 2 or even 3 pages. The featured ads are marked on the top of the site, but usual ones don't. In addition, on the last pages there are archived ads.
ogloszenia = soup.find_all(class_='column-container column_default')

I wanted just to gather the container, but featured and archived ones have also such containers. I also can't just find the 'Lista ogłoszeń' and then find_sibling. Cause on next page there is not such a fieldLista ogloszen, next page without such field.

I suggest to use their Ajax pagination API that returns data about ads in Json format (there is also info if the ad is archived or not):
import json

import requests

api_url = "https://www.nieruchomosci-online.pl/szukaj.html"
params = {"3,mieszkanie,wynajem,,Szczecin:19503": "", "p": "1", "ajax": "1"}

headers = {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0",
}


for params["p"] in range(1, 3):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()

    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    for k, v in data["listAdditionalData"].items():
        print(k)
        print(v["metaTitle"])
        print(v["primaryPrice"], "zł")
        print("ARCHIVE" if v["isArchive"] == "1" else "NOT ARCHIVE")
        print()

Prints:

...

a23621242
Wynajmę mieszkanie 100 m² Szczecin, Świerczewo
4600 zł
NOT ARCHIVE

a24885688
Piękne mieszkanie w kamienicy, Centrum Szczecin
2600 zł
NOT ARCHIVE

a24862202
Ul. Emilii Plater Miejsca postojowe w cenie Szczecin, Centrum
1900 zł
NOT ARCHIVE

...

